# Lock screen audio player notification not appearing when target SDK is 33

Tags: flutter, audio-service

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aa.aaaa"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

When the target SDK is 33, I have a problem with  player control notifications not working in lock screen , but when I set the target SDK to 31, the notifications work properly and appear on the lock screen.

I am using [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages?q=audio_service) and [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) for play audio in my application

Note:-

=> My lock screen notification option is on from my device setting.

=> i am facing this issue in samsung devices only in other device all thing is working well

=> i have samsung galaxy m32 and i have tried in other devices also and in all samsung device i am facing this issue

=> my flutter code is working good i personally think this issue is in plugin.